# Tesseract use image from byte array

Tags: arrays, tesseract

I have an image file that was read into byte array and I'm trying to process it through Tesseract:

```
using (TesseractEngine engine = new TesseractEngine(@"tessdata", "eng", EngineMode.Default))
  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imgByteArray))
  {
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(ms)
    using (Pix img = PixConverter.ToPix(bmp))
      using (Page page = engine.Process(img, PageSegMode.Auto))
  }
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Then I try to do it with the same image through file path:

```
using (TesseractEngine engine = new TesseractEngine(@"tessdata", "eng", EngineMode.Default))
  using (Pix img = Pix.LoadFromFile(@"C:\img1.png"))
    using (Page page = engine.Process(img, PageSegMode.Auto))
```

The second one gives much better results.
How can I use the byte array and get the same results?
In my application I can't work with file paths.